# How time is set in Java methods?

Tags: java, android

In my android app, after getting some validation become true postDescription() method will run.
In onDataChange method i create hashmap in which i added date and time.
and also try to make a new node in firebase database inside of Posts node.
Now suppose, (I might be wrong and i am taking about mili seconds) if internet connectivity is VERY MUCH slow than the time used in postsMAP(HasMap) and  PostRef.child(current_User_ID+SaveCurrentDate+SaveCurrentTime) will be the always same string or not ?

```
private void postDescription()
    {
     UserRef.child(current_User_ID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                    Calendar CalForDate=Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat CurrentDate=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    String SaveCurrentDate=CurrentDate.format(CalForDate.getTime());

                    Calendar CalForTime=Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat CurrentTime=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
                    String SaveCurrentTime=CurrentTime.format(CalForTime.getTime());


                    HashMap postsMAP=new HashMap();
                    postsMAP.put("date",SaveCurrentDate);
                    postsMAP.put("time",SaveCurrentTime);
                    postsMAP.put("description",Description);

                    PostRef.child(current_User_ID+SaveCurrentDate+SaveCurrentTime).updateChildren(postsMAP)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                                {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                                    {                                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "updating successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "error occur while posting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: this not belongs to my question

Answer (score 0):

You should save time in milliSeconds only, as the precision is more. And if you are adding multiple entries using timestamp, it is recomMended to use time in milliSeconds in order to avoid duplicate time entries. You can use System.currentTimeMillis() for this.
Example -

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: If you want finer resolution, use `java.time.Instant.now()` and either calling `toString` for a string in standard ISO 8601 format or ask for a pair of numbers: (a) whole seconds since first moment of 1970 in UTC (`Instant.getEpochSecond`), plus (b) the fractional second as nanoseconds (`Instant::getNano`). Current implementations of `Clock` used by `Instant` capture the current moment in microseconds, not nanoseconds, given the limits of conventional computer clock hardware.